# Dimplejs Vertical 100% Bar Decimal

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js, dimple.js

I working with Dimplejs, I created my chart, however; I am having difficult time setting **tickFormat** to decimal. When you hover over bar you will get **"Percent: 24%"**, but I want is to get whatever is the percent value set too. such **"Percent: 24.1%"**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franktudor/katm9e6s/)

```
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
  myChart.setBounds(65, 45, 505, 315)
  myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "YRMO");
  var y = myChart.addPctAxis("y", "Percent");
  myChart.addSeries("halfit", dimple.plot.bar);
  myChart.addLegend(200, 10, 380, 20, "right");
  y.tickFormat = ".1f";
  myChart.draw();
```

this is not my fiddle, but its same idea, if you change value to decimal. chart rounds the decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just solve my own question for the first time. Here is how it done.

```
 bars.getTooltipText = function (e) {
            return [
                "Point : " + e.aggField[0] + "",
                "Value : " + e.yValue + "%",
                "Series : " + e.cx + ""
            ];
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `addPctAxis` you should pass the value and the function calculate the percentage for you. Then you can set tickFormat to change the percentage value to display decimal values:

`y.tickFormat = ".2%"`;

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcosmarxm/tm3b2ewy/)